# Using nbdime for Jupyter notebooks under PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm, jupyter, dataspell

I'm using [`nbdime`](https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime) to diff and merge Jupyter notebooks, and aside from being a tad slow for large notebooks, I love it. However, when I try to do version control from within PyCharm, my git settings for this seem to be ignored and it does a textual diff of the `.ipynb` files.

My `.gitconfig` has the following, which I believe were set up when I installed `nbdime`:

```
[diff "jupyternotebook"]
        command = git-nbdiffdriver diff
[merge "jupyternotebook"]
        driver = git-nbmergedriver merge %O %A %B %L %P
        name = jupyter notebook merge driver
[difftool "nbdime"]
        cmd = git-nbdifftool diff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[difftool]
        prompt = false
[mergetool "nbdime"]
        cmd = git-nbmergetool merge \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
[mergetool]
        prompt = false
```

From the command line, this works great. (Well, I've never had to do a merge, but the diff works great.)

Also, I see that you can specify an external diff tool in PyCharm, but that appears to be a global setting.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Can you show your settings?

Comment: Would you mind if I updated your title and tags to include DataSpell? :)

Answer (score 8):

*Updated 2021-11-29*

Since this is pretty setup dependant, you may have to adapt the following.

I'm using:

- macos 12.01
- miniconda as my base user python (3.9.7)
- per project i have a mix of virtualenv and conda

To use nbdime to diff my notebooks...

1. First figure out where nbdime is installed for you. On Mac/Linux:
   `which nbdiff-web`
2. In PyCharm or IDEA, Navigate to Preferences -> Tools -> Diff & Merge -> External Diff Tools
3. Make sure "Use external diff tool:" is checked
4. Path to executable: *fully qualified path from step 1*

   - Mine is `/Users/dork/miniconda/bin/nbdiff-web`
5. Parameters: `--ignore-details --ignore-metadata --ignore-outputs %1 %2`

   - the flags assume you don't want to diff execution count, metadata, and outputs
6. Click Apply

To use it:

1. Open a diff of a notebook
2. Click on icon second to last button on the top (before the `?`). Looks like a hammer and wrench. It may be hidden by an expander.

Comment: Thank you so so much - absolutely amazing - a miracle it works (for DataSpell too of course)! Did you manage to get a merge working too?

Comment: Haha. I can't figure out how to launch an external merge tool from within  PyCharm/IDEA/DataSpell even though the I've clicked on the "Enable External Merge Tool". 

FWIW, my path to executable goes to `nbdiff-merge` and my parameters are `--ignore-outputs --ignore-metadata --ignore-id --out %4 %3 %1 %2`

Let me know if you figure something out!

Comment: Ugh, Now this has stopped working for me completely - even the diff - nbdiff-web gives a 422....

Comment: @debugme - Try `nbmerge-web` instead of `nbdiff-merge`

Answer (score 3):

@debugme answer didn't work for me (**under Windows, using Anaconda Python + PyCharm 2018.2**). There were three issues:

- `nbdime` needs Python, but under Anaconda the Python interpreter isn't available globally (i.e. in the `PATH`), only when activating the relevant conda environment.
- Not sure if it was a change in PyCharm or `nbdime` - but my PyCharm only passes two parameters when diffing, and `git-nbdifftool` expects 3.
- The answer explains how to set up `nbdime` for diff, but I wanted it for merges as well.

---

So, this worked for me:

1. Create a batch file `pycharm_nb_diff.bat` with:

   > ```
   > call %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
   > nbdiff-web --ignore-details %*
   > exit /b %errorlevel%
   > ```

   - Note I'm using `nbdiff-web` instead of `git-nbdifftool`.
   - The `--ignore-details` switch ignores some differences when comparing cells (mainly the `execution_count`, which is the small number in square brackets next to the cell). You can remove the switch for a more comprehensive diff.
   - Calling `activate.bat` runs the tool within the conda env (the location I'm using is the default under Windows).
   - BTW, conda 4.6.0 re-introduced [`conda-run`](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/7320), which is preferred over `activate.bat`, but it's currently only supported under Linux.
2. Now set PyCharm to use `pycharm_nb_diff.bat` with the params `%1 %2`.
3. In the same manner, create `pycharm_nb_merge.bat` with `nbmerge-web` instead of `nbdiff-web`, and set PyCharm to use it as a merge tool. Note that the required params for merge are different: `--out %4 %3 %1 %2`

   - thanks to the `exit /b %errorlevel%` line in the script, you can check the box *Trust process exit code* in PyCharm and merges work as expected.